# Upload build/ipa for testing in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

I am using application loader to upload my IPA on TestFlight to make it available for testers to test the app. 
Application loader shows a successfully uploaded message but when I log into iTunesConnect in Apple developer account, I don't see the build in TestFlight under that particular app.

This is what application loader shows. 
[image]

This is what the iTunesConnect shows. 
[image]

Comment: There is another tab `Activity` next to `TestFlight`. Can you see the build there. Usually it appears in `Activity` first with status pending and after some processing, if all good then it shows up in `TestFlight`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invite internal and external tester to test app after invite in test flight show.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and the way to "fix it" was: in ItunesConnect go to the AppStore tab and click on the "Version or Platform" link and select iOS. There create a new version with the exact version number you are uploading.

After this you will be able to see the builds you are uploading and start testing in Testflight.

Hope this helps!